# How to get coordinates of drawed circle Java2D

Tags: java, geometry, java-2d

Let's say I want a sprite to be circulating around certain point. I could draw a circle around this point using drawOval method but how to get specific coordinates of this oval on which moving sprite could be drawn on.

Comment: how about setting the sprites position without actually drawing the circle, would that be a solution? You could just alter the value of the angle and update the position based on that?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman I don't think it's possible any other way, unless you want to grab the screen and perform some edge detection and shape recognition :)

Comment: @EvilTak You could draw the circle on a blank frame and recover all x,y positions that are drawn. That would effectively get to the OPs answer as well, though it seems like a very odd solution.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman I didn't know that, I've never done more than school work in Java (I despise it, even though it shows up as my top tag), but if you're using a custom coordinate system (that is, if you're not using pixels as units) or camera transformations like panning and zooming, that wouldn't really help, because then you'd need to transform back to pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

To get all points on the circumference of an ellipse (or oval), you can use the following formula (`posX` and `posY` are coords of the center of the oval and `width` and `height` are the width and height of the oval respectively):

```
x = posX + cos(angle) * width * 0.5
y = posY + sin(angle) * height * 0.5
```

Where angle goes from 0 to `2 * PI` radians.

You can increment `angle` by something like `delta_time * speed` where `delta_time` is the time it took to render the last frame (or rather, time since the last frame) in seconds and `speed` is the speed (in `unit/second`) at which you want the sprite to move.